# Usage of subprocess.check_output() for searching files inside python

Tags: python

I am using subprocess.check_output() to run the basic "ls" command. From what I understand after reading documentation is that this process can help run a shell command from within the domain of python.

Let us say my example folder is home/ where I have the following files

```
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 aravind aravind     761 Dec  2 10:48 flux_acis_bare_479.dat
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 aravind aravind    2426 Dec  2 10:49 flux_acis_bare_481.dat
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 aravind aravind     759 Dec  2 18:46 flux_acis_hetg_479.dat
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 aravind aravind    2178 Dec  2 18:45 flux_acis_hetg_481.dat
```

If I do an ls search from shell for the keyword "acis", naturally all files are returned.

Now I want to do the same thing from within python.

The following is my attempt

```
     import os
     import subprocess

     os.chdir("home/")
     subprocess.check_output(["ls", "*acis*"])
```

The two " ", " " should run sequentially and I should get back all the files as a result would have been my guess. However the output I get is a file not found error.

```
     Command '['ls', '*acis*']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Disclaimer : I have looked at multiple Stack Overflow questions on subprocess.check_output() and tried to see if my question is a duplicate. If I have missed something please let me know.

Comment: The shell interprets glob patterns, not `ls`. You would need to spawn a shell. Is your actual goal to run `ls`, though, or is it to look for files? ’Cause there are better tools for that, like [the glob module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Comment: My actual goal is indeed to search for files and convert them into a list. I'll look into the glob module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ry-♦ said, `glob` is the module you're looking for. Running `glob.glob("home/*acis*")` will give you a list of files and directories that match the pattern. To match recursively, like if you wanted to find a file such as `home/flux_acis_folder/something_else.dat`, you could use `glob.glob("home/*acis**", recursive=True)`.